# Setting DEADLOCK_PRIORITY in L2S/Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, deadlock

Had a little trouble with deadlocks and one of the actions (aside from the "get rid of the deadlock in the first place" action) is to set the deadlock priority of one particular stored procedure so that it should never be chosen as the victim (it is a lot more important).

I can see how to do this in the stored procedure, but I was wondering, as an academic exercise, if this can be achieved using Entity Framework or LINQ2SQL ?

Thanks
Duncan

Answer (score 0):

You would almost certainly be better off making sure you have the correct indexes; inappropriate or missing indexes are an often overlooked aspect of excessive locking/ blocking.